# why pg_query doesn't work?

Tags: php, html, database, encoding, sql-insert

Now, I have this code for insert to PGSql

```
    $title = pg_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
    $view = pg_escape_string($_POST["view"]);
    $desc = pg_escape_string($_POST["desc"]);

    $insert = pg_query($dbconn,"INSERT INTO product (title, path, description) VALUES('$title','$view','$desc')");
    if(!$insert) {
        echo 'oops';
    }
```

dbconn is working, but insert not a trie put values etc `'{$var}'` but without success :/
All seems good, I desperate!

Comment: Have you checked to see if there were any errors? `pg_last_error`.

Comment: sERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xfd
Well, I guess, it's causes "img/exm.jpg" - path to image, which I'm trying insert.

Comment: Keep the language clean.

Comment: @MarcB don't understand? what you mean? my english? :D I'm sorry, I'm Czech :D

Comment: your `!insert()` message... keep the language clean.

Comment: oh, sorry, I want erase it, but I forger.

Comment: Solved! I have not set UTF-8 in HTML meta